How to sign a WinUI 3 app (packaged or unpackaged)?
I would like to get some guideline on how to sign a WinUI 3 application for usage in deployment to the local C: drive of our users.
Current situation:
Our team has an unpackaged WinUI3 "inhouse" application (an exe file and a couple of DLLs from the nuget packages) that is copied occasionally and manually into a subfolder of our users C:\ drive, let's say C:\CompanyApplications.
Our users start the exe file from there using a desktop shortcurt.
We use the current Windows App SDK version 1.5.2. and .NET 8, C# and the newest version Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 for development.

New situation / required changes:
The security team (a contracted company which manages our company’s network and devices) said that soon, the concept to just execute some "arbitrary" exe file on a normal user’s system will no longer be allowed.
What will be allowed is executing an exe file from a public file share (which has restricted write access) or executing an exe file / an application from the local C: drive (C:\CompanyApplications folder) if the application or exe file is signed.
Currently we would rather not take the approach using the public file share because then "updating" the application would work only if none of our users has it opened and write operations on this directory are possbible.
We will probably be supplied with a PFX certificate file (code signing certificate), but I currently I would not know how to use it for signing the WinUI3 application.
I also do not know whether we have to change to a "packaged application" or if we can keep our "unpackage application" approach in a signed way.
See screenshot below:
I have seen this "sign the output assembly to give it a strong name" section in the WinUI3 project properties, but I do not know whether this is applicable here.



The strong naming feature is like the name says about "naming", it's just to identify the publisher and a given version of a binary, it has nothing to do with exe/dll code signing which is also called "Authenticode" on Windows for which you do require a a code signing certificate. It seems you're looking for packaged signed application https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps

You might like to look at the documentation for Microsoft's SignTool application, which is one way to sign assemblies. Amongst other parameters, you'll need to pass the hash of your code-signing certificate, once you've installed it.

Strong-named assemblies shouldn't be applicable for you. You may need SignTool.

Ok, thank you. I will look into the "SignTool". It seems that I can apply this tool directly to  the exe file of my application, so I do not need to create a msix package (and apply the sign tool to the package)?

Yes, you can apply this tool directly to the exe file.

As a conclusion, Strong-named assemblies shouldn't be applicable for your circumstance. You need SignTool to sign your exe file.
Example for syntax:
signtool sign /f MyCert.pfx /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /fd SHA256 MyFile.exe 


I observed that by applying the signtool, the targeted exe file will increase slightly in size. In addition, it will show a new tab about the digital signatures in the "file properties" dialog that can be called from the windows explorer context menu for the file

I have one more question: During delopment and debugging, is normal or standard practise to also sign the debug version of the exe file (in a postbuidl step)? Or is this uncommon? We are currently experimenting with this and find it hard to include the relatively long command to invoke the sign tool (with an abolute path) together with the path the the exe file which we also have to spefify with an absolut path (because the $(TargetPath) returns a path to a DLL for the executable of an .NET 8 WPF application and no the path to the exe).

@Martin As far as I know, this is uncommon with an exception that you have specific requirements to do this.
